# How to consume WCF service in ASP.NET Core 1 adn VSCode editor?

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core

I'm using [VSCode editor](https://code.visualstudio.com/) from Microsoft to build my first ASP.NET Core 1.0 eb app,  my problem now how can I consume external WCF service in this App ?
I read that using VS 2015 I can add an extension to build the client of WCF, but how to do it using VSCode or any other editor ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can't use the extension with VSCode. Instead you can do a hack, you can download the VSIX file from [Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c3b3666e-a928-4136-9346-22e30c949c08). Rename it as ZIP, extract it. In the extracted folder, under svcutil folder, you can find dotnet-svcutil.exe, where you can specify the URL and other options to generate code.

Comment: But this won't work in another system other than windows. Isn't there any other way ?

Comment: Yes, it will work only in Windows. I think that is the only option.